# Add value from a table to another combine with value from textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I encountered this problem where "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" when i want to insert data from other table and also add value from the textbox.

This is my code:

```
Try
            MySQLCMD = New MySqlCommand
            With MySQLCMD
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO attendance (stud_name, stud_id, sub_name, sub_prof, daytoday, time_in, remarks) VALUES ((SELECT stud_name, stud_id FROM temp_attendance), @sub_name, @sub_prof, @daytoday, @time_in, @remarks)"
                .Connection = con
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@time_in", TextBoxTime2.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_name", TextBoxSubjectName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_prof", TextBoxProfessor.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@daytoday", TextBoxDate.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", "Absent")
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Data saved successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
            CallData()
            ClearData()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Data failed to save !!!" & vbCr & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error Message")
            con.Close()
            Return
        End Try
```

Comment: Please use the `.Add` method instead of `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: Where are you opening your connection? It should not be opened until just before the .Execute. Connections should be disposed. Look up how to use `Using...End Using` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CommandText should looks like this

```
CommandText = "INSERT INTO attendance (stud_name, stud_id, sub_name, sub_prof, daytoday, time_in, remarks) SELECT stud_name, stud_id , @sub_name, @sub_prof, @daytoday, @time_in, @remarks FROM temp_attendance"
```